# pgfplots: How to draw line from 0-like value with loglogaxis

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot some vertical lines (to mark control points on my histogram).

Code to draw the line looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}
\addplot+[sharp plot] coordinates {(14.5, 0.0) (14.5, 1000)};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But result looks like first point was just dropped, because there is no value in logarithmic coordinate to be equal zero. How can I draw line from X axis?

Comment: Be more specific. Where do you want to have your first point? If it is at y=0.0, it appears at minus infinity.

Comment: I want to draw line from X axis. Like a grid line, but with it's own style and label in legend.

Comment: Yes this is a good option in my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pgfplots` comes with a `ycomb` plot style, which does what you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}
\addplot+[ycomb] coordinates {(14.5, 1000)};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are trying to address an `inf` value on an axis, as far as I know, `pgfplots` by default discards that (`unbounded coords=discard`). The quickest fix is to put some small positive value instead of zero and then manually adjust the y axis limits such that the perturbation stays out of the plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[ymin=500]
\addplot+[sharp plot] coordinates {(14.5, 0.1) (14.5, 1000)};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]